# grep and sed with pipe from tail -f appears to be caching

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep, sed

I am trying to get a working system to monitor special logs. I usually just want a very specific pattern which I extract using `grep` and a pipe from `tail -f`. I have noticed that grep does not output everything but instead keeps some lines buffered. I guess that makes sense if you have a pipe that will output everything and then terminate and close the stream.
But with `tail -f` that doesn't work out for me.

The same problem appears with `sed`.

Here is an example command I want to use:

```
clear && tail -F -n1000 /var/log/fail2ban.log | grep 'WARNING.*Ban' | sed s/'fail2ban.actions: WARNING '//g | grep -E --color 'ssh-iptables-perma|$'
```

To provide an example:

The last line of the command above is this:

```
2015-05-04 11:17:24,551 [ssh-iptables] Ban x.x.x.x
```

And using this command:

```
clear && tail -F -n1000 /var/log/fail2ban.log | grep 'WARNING.*Ban' | sed s/'fail2ban.actions: WARNING '//g
```

The last line ist this:

```
2015-05-04 19:45:17,615 [ssh-iptables] Ban y.y.y.y
```

Removing further pipes gets me further to the most recent entries.

How can I possibly avoid this caching in the pipes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `grep`'s option `--line-buffered` and `sed`'s option `--unbuffered`.

Comment: egmont explaind it better but you also gave me the correct option for `sed`.

Comment: A hint from grep's manpage: _This can cause a performance penalty._

Comment: I thought so. But that won't really affect us since there is at maximum a few lines per minute which a good server should be able to handle. But thank you for the warning anyways..

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep`'s `--line-buffered` option.

By default, utilities use line-buffering if their standard output is a terminal, but use bigger buffers (probably 4 or 8 kB) when their output is connected to a file descriptor or a pipe.

You're lucky that `tail -F` uses line-buffering by default, and `grep` has a command line option to enable that. I'm not aware of a generic method to enable line buffering for an arbitrary command.

Comment: For arbitrary commands, you can use the [unbuffer utility](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html).

Comment: Thanks; in the mean time I've found the `stdbuf` utility which seems to be more standard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered